# android bottomnavigation menu is not showing

Tags: user-interface, material-design, android-bottomnav

I want to include Bottom Navigation Menu in my project but it is not working. The menu icons are not showing in Bottom Navigation Menu. I am using Android Studio Arctic Fox. I did all the steps correctly but still facing issue. Here is my code please help me solving this issue. Thanks.

Main Activity Xml

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="#8603A9F4"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

res\ menu\ bottom_nav_menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
        android:title="Home" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/orders"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_notes"
    android:title="Order" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/deposit"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_wallet"
    android:title="Deposit" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/profile"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_person"
    android:title="Profile" />
```

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ahmad.workitservices"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.5'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie:4.2.2"
    implementation 'com.github.smarteist:autoimageslider:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0-alpha01'
}
```

themes.xml

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.WorkitServices" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar.Bridge">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: i have closed the menu tag in bottom_nav_menu. I also tried with FrameLayout but still nothing happened. The icons are not showing in bottom navigation menu.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a Frame Layout to keep the bottom nav as it's child. Also I suppose you have closed the Menu in bottom_nav_menu after the last item. (Also not sure about it but try the code once after removing the android:background property, sometimes it is not feasible but doesn't show error. Happens with me:))

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
 
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/any_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_nav"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
 
    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="#8603A9F4"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"/>
     
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```